# Protocol for opposite gender parent accompanying young children into public toilet

Tags: international-travel, children, hygiene, etiquette

I am a father of 2 quite young girls. Sometimes when we're out they need to use public toilets.

I usually take them into the female toilets, because I don't want them gawking at men openly urinating (btw, I have never understood why men's toilets are designed to maximize genital display by removing all privacy measures, but that's another story). However, if the female toilets are full, I'll use the male ones because with little kids it's about T minus 2 minutes when you are first alerted to their need.

So, is it "OK" for a man go into the female toilets for the purposes of accompanying small girls?

Which countries would it not be OK in?

Which countries would it not be OK for me to bring my daughters into a male toilet?

Are there countries where I should do neither?

---

In my experience in USA and Australia, it's always been OK with any women who happen to be using the toilet (or "bathroom" as Americans call it, despite there being no bathing facilities present) - they can see that my intention is both honorable and harmless and the women seem relaxed and understanding about it.

If the roles were reversed - ie a mother accompanying her young sons into a male toilet - I don't think that would ever be a problem: Men don't seem to care about females in their toilet facilities, but in general the reverse is not true.

Comment: Normally, I do take them to the male bathroom on the assumption that I'm the adult and the kids are there to go along. Sometimes I have to bring her in because *I* have to go which stick me to the male bathroom. Luckily I don't think you've been to SE-Asia, because I was surprised and even uncomfortable that urinals are often *outside* the bathroom, so while i a bar in Thaland, you can see pen pissing away. Same setup in Malaysia. In some modern countries I see often *family* bathrooms now to solve some of these issues.

Comment: Slightly different situation, in the municipality pool (the Netherlands) the changing rooms have the statement that the gender of the adult decides which gender room to use.

Comment: @Willeke changing rooms are a completely different thing. I would never go into a female change room!

Comment: I bet Parenting.SE has answers to this. Nevertheless I like this question here.

Comment: I think there's only about 40000 results if you google this

Comment: @JoErNanO I had a look on parenting, and I could only find [At what age should a child stop accompanying a parent into the “wrong” public toilet?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/at-what-age-should-a-child-stop-accompanying-a-parent-into-the-wrong-public-to) and [At what age should parent of opposite sex stop taking their children to changing room?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/28483/at-what-age-should-parent-of-opposite-sex-stop-taking-their-children-to-changing?rq=1). Incidentally, their SE doesn't have a hygiene tag.

Comment: This is currently a bit too broad. Please remove the question asking to list all countries where you can do X or Y, or restrict yourself to a smaller area - e.g. Europe.

Comment: @JonathanReez how is this too broad? If it isn't obvious, I am asking for a list of countries where this is OK and where it's not OK.

Comment: There are 200+ countries out there. Do you expect us to provide information for every single one of them in one answer?

Comment: @JonathanReez no, just the ones with male and female public toilets (which cuts the list way down)